How can I make my scrolling smooth like the attached website?
Currently, I've tried the  html {scroll-behavior: smooth;} addition to my global style file but it is no where near the extent of smooth scrolling featured here: https://fireart.studio/blog/20-best-futuristic-website-examples-to-inspire-you/
It seems to have some sort of momentum to it and is therefore not choppy like a regular scroll bar. I have also noticed it's quite moderate in speed compared to if I were to scroll as fast as I can on a regular scroll bar, which could be a second component to why it feels so smooth.
I've looked through a few other answers and I haven't been able to find how to do the scrolling specifically like this. I appreciate any advice/insight.

FWIW, I absolutely hate it when a website hijacks my browser's scrolling behaviour (I have smooth-scrolling disabled under chrome://flags) - just because something looks cool doesn't mean it's good for usability.

This is for a blog I'm making so I believe the smoother scrolling will make it a lot more satisfying to read. I understand what you mean when it comes to any other website, though.

Hey Joey I had a similar question some years back Back To Top Button Behaviour
For the scrolling behavior, yes the typical smooth scroll does not change its momentum, it's more "linear" and your goal is to have a scroll with a bit more of inertia. If you'd like to build this with just vanilla javascript you can use the following:


window.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  let scrollAmount = event.deltaY;
  let scrollInterval = setInterval(() => {
    window.scrollBy(0, scrollAmount);
    scrollAmount *= 0.8; // Adjust the deceleration factor as needed
    if (Math.abs(scrollAmount) < 1) {
      clearInterval(scrollInterval);
    }
  }, 10);
});



Another option is using a javascript library like Fluid Scroll
or Smooth Scroll
